# How to process data passed in success function in jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I need to process two lists in `Ajax` success function. The below simple code works well for a single list but doesn't work with 2 lists. How can we process 2 lists separately in a `success function`.

**jQuery Ajax**

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
            //do something with v
        });
    });
}
```

**views.py**

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lst2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

context = {
    'labels'   : lst1,
    'sk_labels': lst2
}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Why don't you follow your words? Do it in separate $.each one after another if they do not depend on each other

Comment: @Shubhranshu this way `$.each(data, function() { $.each(this, function(k, v) { //do something with v }); $.each(this, function(k, v) { //do something with v }); });` or this `$.each(data, function() { $.each(this, function(k, v) { //do something with v }); }); $.each(data, function() { $.each(this, function(k, v) { //do something with v }); });` both not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had almost the same problem. Solution was pretty simple.

Try using in first Jquery function call. It helped me parsing data correctly.

> JSON.parse(data);

```
success: function(data) {
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function() {
    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
        //do something with v
    });
});}
```

Comment: but how does it process 2 lists separately

Comment: By separately You mean diffrent action for each list, or first parse one list then second?

Comment: Parse one list and then another list

Comment: I was talking about something like this `$.each(data.list1, function(k, v) { // Do something });`, `$.each(data.list2, function(k, v) { // Do something });`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)'s documentation. Try the following:

```
success: function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(contextKey, values) {
    $.each(values, function(index, value) {
      // do something with value
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: it iterates over one list then another, but cannot distinguish between the two lists. Say I want to store 1st list in some variable and 2nd list in some other variable.

Comment: @User `data[contextKey]` is your list within the first loop. You can also access `data.labels` and `data.sk_labels` directly if you wish.